# How to resolve this algebra equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$f = X^3 - 12X + 8$$ $a $-  complex number, $a$ is a root for $f$

$b = a^2/2 - 4 $.

Show that $f(b) = 0$

This is one of my theme exercises ... Some explanations will be appreciated ! Thank you all for your time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(b) &= f(\frac{a^2}{2} - 4) \\
&= (\frac{a^2}{2} - 4)^3 - 12(\frac{a^2}{2} - 4) + 8  \\
&= \frac{a^6}{8} - 3a^4 + 24 a^2 - 64 - 6a^2 + 48 + 8 \\
&= \frac{a^6}{8} -3a^4 + 18a^2 -8
\end{align*}

On the other hand,
$$
f(a) = a^3 - 12a + 8 = 0
$$
and therefore 
\begin{align*}
0 = 0^2 &= (a^3 - 12a + 8)^2 \\
&= a^6 - 24a^4 + 16a^3 + 144 a^2 - 192a + 64 \\
&= (a^6 - 24a^4 + 144 a^2 - 64) + (16a^3 - 192a + 128) \\
&= 8(\frac{a^6}{8} -3a^4 + 18a^2 -8) + 16(a^3 - 12a + 8)\\
&= 8f(b) + 16f(a) \\
&= 8f(b)
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
f(b)=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

As $a$ is root of $f = X^3 - 12X + 8=0, a^3-12a+8=0$

Now, $b=\frac{a^2}2-4\implies a^2=2(b+4)=2b+8$

So, from  $a^3-12a+8=0, a(2b+8)-12a+8=0\implies a=-\frac8{2b+4}=-\frac4{b+2}$

So, $$\left(-\frac4{b+2}\right)^3-12\cdot \left(-\frac4{b+2}\right)+8=0$$

On simplification we  get , $$b^3-12b+8=0$$